# How to get post with multiple but not all tags in common

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I get posts which have at least two tags in common?

**tag__in => $args**  shows posts which have ***either*** tag in common

**tag__and => $args** for post which have ***all*** tags in common

What i need is get all posts which have ***some tags*** in common, more than one tag and less than all tags in common.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you put this into better context? Show the code that uses these *tags*.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 'tax_query' parameter in WP_Query. I haven't tried to do exactly what you're trying to do, but it should work.  The tax_query parameter is an array of separate taxonomy queries, with each query specifying the taxonomy, the term_id(s) and an operator like "IN" or "NOT IN".

Look at WP_Tax_Query in wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 534 and WP_Query::parse_tax_query in wp-includes/query.php (line 1674).

[Here's an example of using tax_query with WP_Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870825/wordpress-help-with-select-posts-with-query-post)

Hope this helps.